# What is the complexity of Hoffman and Pavley's Nth best path algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, graphs, algorithm-analysis, shortest-path

I am currently working on a project where I'm using an implementation of Hoffman and Pavley's "[Method for the Solution of the Nth Best Path Problem](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=320998.321004)" to find n-th best path through a directed graph. The implementation is based on [QuickGraph's Ranked Shortest Path implementation](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Ranked%20Shortest%20Path).

I have been trying to determine the complexity of Hoffman and Pavley's algorithm as well as QuickGraph's implementation, but without any luck -- so basically my question is if someone knows the complexity of the original method proposed by Hoffman and Pavley as well as the complexity of QuickGraph's implementation?

Comment: Seems [David Eppstein](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/pubs/p-kpath.html) algorithm is faster one : $O(m + n \log n + k \log k)$. If you really interested in best algorithm you can change your way.